# Returning Promise says Promise Pending, Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am new to Nodejs and first time working on promises so now the context is when I try to return promise it shows status Promise . How to fix it can anyone guide me through this?

Here is the code where I am calling a function that will return a promise. bold line showing where I want to return that promise and store in an object.

```
for(let i = 0; i<responseArray.length; i++){
                    let dollar = {
                            amount : 0
                    };
                    if(i == 1){
                        continue;    
                    }                   
                   dollar.amount = **currenciesService.getCurrencyLatestInfo(responseArray[i].currency);**
                   dollarAmount.push(dollar);
                }
                console.log("$", dollarAmount);
```

Here is a code which is returning promise.

```
const getCurrencyLatestInfo = function(currency) {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym='+currency+'&tsyms='+currency+',USD', { json: true }, (err, res, body) => 
    {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            var result= body;
            resolve(result);
            console.log("RESULT: ",result.USD); 
        }
    });
})
```

}

Comment: Output is like :
 [ { amount: Promise { <pending> } },
  { amount: Promise { <pending> } },
  { amount: Promise { <pending> } },
  { amount: Promise { <pending> } },
  { amount: Promise { <pending> } },
  { amount: Promise { <pending> } },
  { amount: Promise { <pending> } },
  { amount: Promise { <pending> } },
  { amount: Promise { <pending> } },
  { amount: Promise { <pending> } },
  { amount: Promise { <pending> } },
  { amount: Promise { <pending> } } ]

Comment: It's obvious that returning a promise will result in the calling funciton receiving a promise, isn't it? I mean, if you return `true`, the calling function gets `true`, etc. Anyway, to get the resolved value of a promise, one needs to use the `.then` method of the promise.

Comment: The promises haven't been fulfilled yet. You need to wait for the `amount` promise to be fulfilled with something like `.then()` or `await` before using it's value... https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises#promise-terminology

Comment: also [`request-promise`](https://github.com/request/request-promise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to wait for those promises to resolve before you can use the resolved values

here is a small rewrite of your loop that should work

```
let promises = [];
for(let i = 0; i<responseArray.length; i++){
    if(i == 1){
        continue;    
    }                   
   let dollar = currenciesService.getCurrencyLatestInfo(responseArray[i].currency)
       .then(amount => ({amount})); // do you really want this?
   promises.push(dollar);
}
Promise.all(promises)
.then(dollarAmount =>console.log("$", dollarAmount))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

This should result in an array like `[{amount:123},{amount:234}]` as your code seems to expect

The above can also be simplified to

```
Promise.all(
    responseArray
    .filter((_, index) => index != 1)
    .map(({currency}) => 
        currenciesService.getCurrencyLatestInfo(currency)
        .then(amount => ({amount})) // do you really want this?
    )
)
.then(dollarAmount =>console.log("$", dollarAmount))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Note: your original code suggests you want the results to be in the form `{amount:12345}` - which seems odd when you want to console.log("$", ....) ... because the console output would be something like

```
$ [ { amount: 1 }, { amount: 0.7782 } ]
```

given two results of course - can't see your `responseArray` so, am only guessing

Comment: Thank you for your solution there is nore pending promises but it doesn't showing any output. What does it means?

Comment: `there is nore pending promises` - what does this mean? Are you saying that `console.log("$", dollarAmount)` is never called? Perhaps there's a rejection happening

Comment: I've added rejection handling - does that get called?

Comment: got what? I asked a question ?!?

Comment: It doesn't getting any rejection. I've tried your rejection handling. I put resolve method in setTimeout method now its showing undefined values.Does this means we are getting response back but not in a required format?

Comment: not sure, let me re-check the code - does `console.log("RESULT: ",result.USD);` get output for each request?

Comment: Yes that is showing the required results but where I am returning the value cause undefined results. i.e while loging dollarAmount Array.

Comment: Oh, I see something in my code I forgot to remove - you should be getting errors if you run it!

Comment: Oh, I see where I screwed up ... hang on

Comment: This should now result in `dollarAmount` being a series of amounts - ignore my other ramblings :p

Comment: still getting undefined results

Comment: With reference to your comments on my code, I just want the data fetching from API into my **dollar** object.

Comment: I still can't **guess** the expected results

Comment: `still getting undefined results` - I don't, so you copied it wrong